# SWT Browser widget no longer displaying PDFs from local filesystem

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have been using the SWT Browser widget in my RCP app to display generated documents (mainly PDFs).

Recently, the widget stopped displaying PDFs. Just a dark grey background is displayed. There is a noticable delay when larger files are loaded but the result is always the same.

It will still show other file types, such as TXT, XML, PNG, HTML with no problems. All files are in the user's temporary folder (Windows). Therefore, it doesn't seem to be an access problem.

I have been migrating the app from Kepler to 2020/3 so I'm guessing that something has changed in the platform. On the other hand, the company has been moving from IE to Chrome as its' standard browser but I don't think that should be an issue here.

I have FF, IE and Chrome installed (Windows10) and each of these can display PDFs.

Do I need to explicity register a PDF plugin in the Browser or something similar?

I used this View to test interactively:

````
package testbrowserpdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class View extends ViewPart {
    public View() {
    }
    public static final String ID = "TestBrowserPdf.view";

    @Inject
    IWorkbench workbench;

    private Browser browser;

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        
        Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        
        Label lblPath = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        lblPath.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        lblPath.setText("Choose file...");
        
        Button btn = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
        btn.setText("...");
        btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog (parent.getShell(), SWT.OPEN);
                String file = dialog.open();
                if(file != null) {
                    File f = new File(file);
                    try {
                        lblPath.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
                        browser.setUrl(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            
            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        
        browser = new Browser(parent, 0);
        browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        browser.setFocus();
    }
}```
````

Comment: I have a similar issue with Windows, but the issue was from June 29th https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-20h2#1637msgdesc that after this update the web browser is grey.
And seems like an issue with adobe acrobat reader and the native browser. If I install foxit reader for example then the pdf shows normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was a temporary problem (as suggested by @korogui). It is now July21 and the embedded PDF viewer is working again.